# Unable to call method from another method of the same class in JAVA

Tags: java, class, methods

I have made a simpler version of Battle ship game in which you play with the computer.
For some reason i am unable to call a method. I want you to help me with that. Also let me know if you have any suggestions on how i can improve the quality of the program.
**Some information that you may need to solve the problem**

 **I AM UNABLE TO CALL mapchanger() method in callGameManager() method**
Error: I don't receive any error, But whatever i put in mapChanger() method doesn't work.
OS : Ubuntu 19.10
Java jdk 14
Text Editor : Sublime Text (unlicensed)

Code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        secondClass please = new secondClass();
        System.out.println("Welcome to BATTLE SHIP !!!");
        System.out.println("If you want to play enter Y else N");
        String response = input.next();
        response = response.toUpperCase();      
        if(response.equals("Y")){please.callGameManager();}
        else if (response.equals("N")){System.out.println("OK,nice to see you \nBii !");}
        else if (response.equals("HACKERMAN")){please.sethackermanMode(); please.callGameManager();}
    }
}
class secondClass
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> map = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> ship = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int coordinate;
    private userInput io = new userInput();
    private boolean hit;
    private int triesYouHave=3;
    private int hitCounter=0;
    private int attempts=0;
    private boolean hackermanMode = false;

    void sethackermanMode()
    {
        hackermanMode =true;
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("HACKERMAN mode : ACTIVE ");
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }

    void callGameManager()
    {
        mapMaker();
        if(hackermanMode == true){printTheMapAndShip();}

        io.getGuess();
        for(int j =0 ;j<9999999;j++)
        {   attempts++;         
            if(checker() == false)
            {

                mapChanger();
                System.out.println("MISS you have "+(--triesYouHave)+" tries left");
                if(triesYouHave==0 ){System.out.println("You loose , looser\nYou made "+attempts+" attempts");break;}   
                io.getGuess();
                checker();

            }
            else if(checker() == true)
            {
                hitCounter++;
                triesYouHave++;

                System.out.println("HIT \t\t\tyou have "+(--triesYouHave)+" tries left");
                if(hitCounter == 3){System.out.println("You win , winner\nYou did it in "+attempts+" attempts");break;}
                io.getGuess();
                checker();              
            }           
        }
    }

    void mapChanger()
    {
        //ship.remove(io.setGuess);
        System.out.println("Change the map sir...PLease !!!!");
    }

    boolean checker()
    {
        hit = ship.contains(io.setGuess());
        return hit;
    }
    void mapMaker()
    {
        map.addAll(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6));

        //RANDOM ASSIGNER FOR COORDINATES OF SHIP
        coordinate = random.nextInt(map.size()-1);//ASIGNS a random number to coordinate variable between 0 and map.size-1 = 6

        if(coordinate != 0 && coordinate != map.size()-1)
        {
            ship.addAll(Arrays.asList(coordinate-1,coordinate,coordinate+1));
        }
        else if(coordinate==0)
        {
            ship.addAll(Arrays.asList(coordinate,coordinate+1,coordinate+2));
        }
        else
        {
            ship.addAll(Arrays.asList(coordinate-2,coordinate-1,coordinate));
        }
    }


    void printTheMapAndShip()//HACKER MAN
    {
        System.out.println("Map : "+map);
        System.out.println("ship : "+ship);     
    }

}

class userInput
{   
    private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int guess;
    void getGuess()
    {
        guess = input.nextInt();
    }
    int setGuess()
    {
        return guess;
    }
}
```

**P.S. : If you can get that reference you are amazing !**

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Stultuske I dont get any error.It just doesn't print the statement in the mapChanger() method.

Comment: That means checker was not false and it didn't go inside the if block. If you weren't able to call the method then there would be a compilation error.

Comment: @Nishit that's not the case.Everything else in the false condition works perfectly.

Comment: Btw you mixed up `setGuess` and `getGuess` in your class `userInput`. They should be the other way around (setters -> set, getters -> get) :)

Comment: @itzFlubby yeah, I'll correct that . It doesn't have any effect on the program though, if i am right.

Comment: Use a debugger. Or put a print right before, after and inside the method you want to check. Then you will see what locations you visit and what not. Seriously, invest 5 minutes into learning how to use a debugger. Then this will be super easy for you to check and solve.

Comment: Does it goes in a hung state - Cause I see that io.getGuess(); method will wait until you give a number to guess. If you enter the number then everything should work fine. Can you please tell me how are you running the code? I mean what inputs you are passing???

Comment: @RohitGarg correct, it doesn't. It's just for clarity, so you won't get confused when your program gets longer and more complex :)

Comment: Thanks guys for your time and effort . I just fixed it,check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it .

Remember when i said that the text editor is unlicensed  ?

Well , it seems like it has broken.

The above code was pasted from Sublime Text.
But,when i checked the java file in notepad++,the method didn't even existed !!!
So , I copied the above code,pasted in notepad++ , ran the program and it has started working now.

Sorry and thanks !

**Please get your text editor licensed if you are working on a bigger project ! 
 it just wasted by whole day to fix !**

Comment: It is quite unlikely that this is caused by an (unlicensed or not) version of SublimeText. Most likely, you just forgot to save your file.

Comment: @Stultuske no, I actually have auto save enabled so, that's not possible. Doesn't matter though, I have switched to Atom.

Comment: auto-save and such are 'nice to haves', those are (in many cases) the first thing to be disabled in an unlicensed version.